# React-Native 404 on Axios call first time... fine on 2nd

Tags: react-native, axios

So I am building a simple app that basically gets a device ID then sets some data for that device ID.

The API calls work, and the URLs are all fine.

The weird thing is when testing this app on the simulator... when I run the function, it throws a 404. However, if I click the button again, it runs just fine. If I put new data in the text input, it throws a 404, push the button again it works fine.

I have tested all the input setters and all are storing in state before the button push. So I dont think that is the issue...

here is the axios call

```
 const setDevice = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setShowModal(false)
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url + serialNumber, {
        headers: { Authorization: authHeader },
      });
      setId(response.data.mobile_devices[0].id);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(error.message)
      setError("Something went Wrong");
      setIsLoading(false);
      setShowModal(false)
      setShowErrorModal(true)
    }
    await axios.put(url + id, body, {
      headers: { Authorization: authHeader, "Content-Type": "application/xml" },
    });
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
```

I have even tried to hard code the API alls just to see if that was the problem, and it was not. so making the text inputs not even a factor I still get this error..

Again, running it a 2nd time, works.

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Request failed with status code 404]
- node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:15:17 in createError
- node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:16:9 in settle
- node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:52:6 in handleLoad
- node_modules/event-target-shim/dist/event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:567:4 in setReadyState
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:389:6 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:425:19 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:112:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:373:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:111:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I have found the problem. The Put request is not getting the right data from the Get request.

I did some error handling and found the problem.